# Pre Get Posts / Multiple Meta Keys / Orderby Single Key

Tags: meta-query

Tried more than a few variances to enable my `pre_get_posts` callback function to display posts that possess one, or both, of 2 separate meta_keys, upon display to then `orderby` a single meta_key.

[Here is a pastebin of the various attempts](http://pastebin.com/QCcgRMHm)

Namely I am able to display correctly via 2 separate keys but am unable to then orderby a single one of them, what am I missing to do this?

Comment: If something happens to that pastebin this question becomes unintelligible. Please include your code in your question. It looks to me like the last attempt, with the `meta_query` is the closest to correct. I don't have time to take a shot at a solution right now though.